# Drawing the upper case string in the NSString class using NSString drawInRect class method

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to solve the exercises behind the programming with obj c. The questions says to draw the uppercase version of a string using the drawing methods of NSString class. I have so far created a category for the same and when I try to implement the method for draw it says my selector does not have a visible @interface in the NSString class. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
#import "NSString+NSStringDrawing.h"  
@implementation NSString (StringDrawing)
-(void)upperCaseGreeting: (NSString *) greeting{
    NSString *uppercaseGreetingVar = [greeting uppercaseString ];
    NSRect aRect;
    CGSize size1 = {9,5};
    aRect.size = size1;                                  
    [uppercaseGreetingVar drawInRect: aRect withAttributes: 0];
}
```

In the main method:

```
 NSString *obj = [NSString new];
 [obj upperCaseGreeting:@"ABCDEF"];
```

Everything gets executed till it reaches drawInRect method. I get the following error:

```
-[__NSCFString drawInRect:withAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100302130
2014-07-23 00:47:48.964 SS[5324:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString drawInRect:withAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100302130'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff912c425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90e30e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff912c712d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91222272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91221df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   SS                                  0x000000010000241e -[NSString(StringDrawing) upperCaseGreeting:] + 222
    6   SS                                  0x00000001000027bb main + 875
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9594d5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Some code would be appreciated too.

Comment: Hello. Your question is lacking in details. Please post some code to get some help. Also asking to solve school exercises is not well seen on SO.

Comment: Why do you need a category on the `NSString` class to get an uppercase string? What's wrong with the standard `uppercaseString` method?

Comment: This is no school exercise. I'm learning Objective C out of my own interest for it. I'm reading the developer's document and working my way through it. The question there is as follows: Add a category to NSString in order to add a method to draw the uppercase version of a string at a given point, calling through to one of the existing NSStringDrawing category methods to perform the actual drawing. These methods are documented in NSString UIKit Additions Reference for iOS and NSString Application Kit Additions Reference for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your category header (`NSString+MyCoolCategory.h`) in the file where you intend to use it.

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // interface file
//@interface NSString (NSStringAdditions)
-(void)upperCaseString:(NSString*)greeting;
-(void)sayHi;
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)aRect;
//@end

Comment: #import "NSString+NSStringAdditions.h" // implementation file
#import "XYZView.h"

@implementation NSString (NSStringAdditions)


-(void)upperCaseString:(NSString*)greeting{

    NSString *str = [greeting uppercaseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)aRect{
    
    NSRect rect = aRect;
    
    aRect.origin.x=9;
    aRect.origin.y=5;
    [@"abcde" drawInRect:rect];
    
    }

-(void)sayHi{
    [self upperCaseString:(NSString*)@"abcde"];
}

end